# how to arrange all columns of data table in descending order in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data table:

```
V1  V2 V3

3   4  9

4   7  4

2   8   3
```

I want to arrange all columns in descending order at once. I tried setorder and order function but they are processing only one column at once.

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Do you mean `df[, lapply(.SD, sort, decreasing = TRUE)]` ?

Comment: hi, i didnt how to use .sd here. thanks.this works